# Is Java LinkedHashMap is same as C#'s SortedList

Tags: java, c#

I am porting some Java code to C#. From my analysis it seems `LinkedHashMap` and `SortedList` are same. Both provides Key Value pair collection backed by linked list and got an O(1) look up time. Also both keeps the elements in insertion order.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: "Also both keeps the elements in insertion order." Um, no - `SortedList` keeps the elements in *key* order. If you insert an entry with 1 as the key then an entry with 0 as the key, the entries will be in order 0, 1.

Comment: From the docs: "Represents a collection of key/value pairs that are sorted by the keys and are accessible by key and by index."

Comment: Also, I believe the lookup time on `SortedList` is O(log n), not O(1)...

Comment: And the general behavior is that `SortedList`, as the name implies, sorts the keys. Therefore definitely more like `TreeMap`, functionally.

Comment: @Skeet Thanks. Is there any collection in C# equivalent to `LinkedHashMap`?

Comment: Not in the standard library, no. But you can *reasonably* easily build it with a `Dictionary<TKey, LinkedListNode<TValue>>` and a parallel `LinkedList<TValue>`.

Comment: @Skeet. Ok. So in c# what is the difference between `SortedDictionary` and `SortedList`?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319 It goes into a fair amount of detail...